# Tensorflow matmul how to deal with channel=None

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix-multiplication, tensor

I am trying to do matmul of two tensors, one is [None, 4, 256], and the other is its transpose (I use tf.transpose and got a tensor [256, 4, None]). The expected result is a [4, 4] tensor. When I use matmul, it returns an error. I am wondering, how can I get the expected result? Thank you!

```
#inputs: [None, 4, 256]
inputs_transpose = tf.transpose(inputs, perm = [0, 2, 1]) #[None, 256, 4]
temp_weights = tf.matmul(inputs, inputs_transpose) #[4, 4]expected
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Tensowflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor)

"Note: This function diverges from default Numpy behavior for float and string types when None is present in a Python list or scalar. Rather than silently converting None values, an error will be thrown."

Tensowflow does not accept None values while creating tensors.
I tried to recreate the setup you had on my system and got this error message:

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'list'> to Tensor. Contents: [None, 4, 256]. Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

You would need to explicitly handle the None by replacing it with a 0 before attempting to use the python list.